# Auto generated login authentication in spring MVC is not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have spring MVC project which gives an output before adding auto generated login authentication filter. But after adding filter i am not getting an output? It gives resource not found 404 error. What is the problem in my code. Actually i want to add this authentication if the url is /books. Following are the related files of my project.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
     xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee    

  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
     id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SpringMVC</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SpringMVC</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/securityconfig.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springFramework.web.filter.DelegationFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

securityconfig.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">

<sec:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/books" access="ROLE_USER"/>
    <sec:form-login/>
    <sec:logout logout-url="/j_security_logout"/>
</sec:http>

<sec:authentication-manager>
    <sec:authentication-provider>
        <sec:user-service>
            <sec:user name="test" password="123" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN"/>
            <sec:user name="bob" password="mypassword" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
        </sec:user-service>
    </sec:authentication-provider>
</sec:authentication-manager>
```

Dependencies for spring security:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- security also needs the following to be present -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Book controller is as:

```
@Controller
public class BookController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String redirectRoot() {
        return "redirect:/books";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/books", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getAll(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("books", bookDao.getAll());
        return "bookList";
    }
}
```

Comment: What about your security login page? Do you have any controller for it?

Comment: No. I think there is no need of  login controller because it is auto . Am i right?

Comment: Ok, you are using auto generated login form. Please check my answer and try it

Answer (score 0):

Try like this. You have configured use-expressions to true, so you cannot simply add the requested role as is in the access attribute:

```
<sec:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/books" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
    <sec:form-login/>
    <sec:logout logout-url="/j_security_logout"/>
</sec:http>
```